# Original 7 Mortal Kombat Characters not in other games?

Tags: mortal-kombat-1992

Of the 7 fighters from the original Mortal Kombat game (1992), are there any that haven't made it as a playable character in the other games of the series?

When I say other games in the series I don't mean Anthologies or Shaolin Monks etc. I'm strictly talking the ladder-based fighters from the series that we know and love.

Comment: You can check the [List of MK Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mortal_Kombat_media) and then look at the **Characters/Playable Characters/Roster** section of each game such as [MK1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_(1992_video_game)). If it's missing the roster then I would imagine Google can help out; but I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mortal_Kombat_characters#Character_overview)

Of the seven originals, only Kano and Sonya were not in MK 2.  They were both in MK 3.

Fun Facts: Only Sub-Zero has been in every single game to date.  Skarlet is the only character (aside from new ones in the latest game) to have only a single appearance.

Answer (score 2):

Raiden and Scorpion weren't in Mortal Kombat 3 (not Ultimate).